# How can I make have UIPageViewController to only scroll on the root controller of UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that has a navigation controller and a view controller. I want to make it, so that if there is a new pushed or a new modular view opened, the page view controller scrolling was disabled. So, I added Restoration ID to the root view controller of the UINavigationController and added the following code for the data source:

```
// viewDidLoad
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([feedViewController],
    direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse,
    animated: false, completion: nil);

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if self.feedViewController.visibleViewController.restorationIdentifier != "FeedViewCtrl" {
        return nil;
    }

    if viewController == self.friendsViewController {
        return self.feedViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if self.feedViewController.visibleViewController.restorationIdentifier != "FeedViewCtrl" {
        return nil;
    }

    if viewController == self.feedViewController {
        return self.friendsViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This doesn't work because these functions get called when a page is being scrolled. How can I achieve this functionality? Besides creating Custom Segues.

Comment: >> "if there is a new pushed or a new modular view opened, the page view controller scrolling was disabled".

If you present something modally on top of `UIPageViewController`, you cannot interact with it anymore. It is unclear what is your problem. And how you have a `UIPageViewController` that has a navigation controller and a view controller? You mean one of controllers is `UINavigationController` and other is general `UIViewController`?

Comment: Yes. I haven't checked the modal controller yet but with navigation controller, I can go to the UIViewController by swiping to the right...

Comment: In docs it says for `dataSource`: If nil, user gesture-driven navigation will be disabled. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't know how to use dataSource with NavigationController, then I created a custom navigation controller that worked with this. And now I am happy :)

Comment: @Gasim What did you end up doing ?